# Is it possible to write a packaging.package to a stream without having to save it to a file first?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a System.IO.Packaging.Package in memory (it is a WordprocessingDocument) and want to stream it down to browser to save it. The word document has been modified by the MVC-based application and the resulting file has been modified for the current request.

I understand the package represents a 'zip' file containing a number of parts. These parts include headers, footers and main body document. I've modified each individually and now want to stream the package back to the user.

I can get the individual part streams... package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/document.xml", UriKind.Relative)).GetStream()

However I'm missing how to get an output stream on the entire document (package)- without writing to the file system.

Thanks in advance

No- what I think I need is something like this... I've already read in the template document and made modifications in memory. Now I want to stream a modified document (leaving the template un-touched) back to the user.

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        WordprocessingDocument docOut =
            WordprocessingDocument.Create( stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

        foreach (var part in package.GetParts())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(part.GetStream()))
            {
                PackagePart newPart = docOut.Package.CreatePart(
                    part.Uri, part.ContentType );
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(newPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately- this produces a 'corrupt' word document...

Answer (score 1):

[**OpenXmlPackage.Close Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close.aspx) saves all changes in all parts to the underlying store. If you opened the package from a stream, just use that stream:

```
public Stream packageStream() {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var wrdPk = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    // Build the package ...
    var docPart = wrdPk.AddMainDocumentPart();
    docPart.Document = new Document(
        new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Hello world.")))));
    // Flush all changes
    wrdPk.Close();
    return ms;
}
```